# CSV Reader empty values java

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have this CSV:

```
0,102000082,,2,125,'Battery location','Left-hand drive',2,2
0,300000029,102000082,3,895,'Behind the cab','Left',2,-7
0,102000082,,4,127,'Battery location','Right-hand drive',4,4
            ^-----
```

I use `csvReader` to map to a bean

```
    public static List<BatteryBean> loadAndRead{
    File csvFilename = new File("C:\\my.csv");
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));

    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
    strat.setType(BatteryBean.class);
    String[] columns = new String[] { "ktypnr","sentenceId","parentId","sortOrder", "adjItemNoteId","sentText","itemNoteText","parentSortOrder1","parentSortOrder10" };
    strat.setColumnMapping(columns);
    CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
    List<BatteryBean> list = csv.parse(strat, csvReader);
    return list;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        List<BatteryBean> list = loadAndRead("C:\\work\\battery_report_raw.csv");

        for (Object object : list) {
            BatteryBean bb = (BatteryBean) object;
            System.out.println(bb.getKtypnr());
        }
   }
```

So the problem is that the file contains empty strings between ,, and I get an exeption at parsing :

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

I resolved. I have another question

```
Csv file
ktypnr  sentence_id    parent_id    sort_order  adj_item_note_id      sent_text              iem_note_text
0         102000082                  2                  125             Battery location'   Left-hand drive'
0         300000029    102000082     3                  895             Behind the cab'        Left'
0         102000082                  4                  127             Battery location'       Right-hand drive'
0         300000029    102000082     5                  898             Behind the cab'        Right'
```

So if one sentence_id = one parent_id i should combine those two so that looks like this(example first line and second line) but I should consider also the sort_order:

```
0, Battery location, Left-hand drive, Behind the cab, Left
```

I don't know how to proceed

Comment: change your bean so that it is a string?

Comment: Obvious exception. What else you are expecting ??

Comment: Yes, changed to a String, and then I will make a parse if it is not null.

Comment: Where's `BatteryBean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `parentId` to `String` data type in BatteryBean. It seems it is integer.